# .Net Core Azure Active Directory Authentication Problems (photos)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, postman

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.bruttin.com/2017/11/21/azure-api-postman.html

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using the default template of .net core web api 2.2 in visual studio 2019 and I want to use Azure AD to authenticate.  To test the authentication I am using Postman, but I can't get it to work.  The photos below show the steps in order in that I am trying.

AuthURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
TokenURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

1. Create Project
   [image: Create Project]
2. Choose API
   [image: Choose API]
3. Enter Domain and check "Read Directory Data"
   [image: Enter Domain]
4. appsettings.js is generated
   [image: appsettings.js]
5. Default StartUp.cs File
   [image: StartUp.cs]
6. Values Controller user the Authorize Attribute
   [image: Values Controller Authorization]
7. Generate a Secret in Azure Portal
   [image: Azure Portal Secret]
8. Fill out token request form in PostMan - Successfully get token.
   [image: Postman token request - Successfully created]
9. Attempt to use the token and access is denied.
   [image: Access Denied]

What am I doing wrong!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> AuthURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" TokenURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

One point is you are acquire Azure AD V2.0 tokens , if that is an Azure AD v2.0 Web API , you should append `/v2.0` to your `Authority`  when config the web api , see [source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiStartupHelpers.cs#L41) of [Microsoft Identity Web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web) .

You could click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/20bfaedb8ea1ec15bb49551be7eb448b6c60217e/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API/TodoListService) for code sample about web api which protected by Azure AD V2.0 .

If you are using the Azure AD V1.0 ,  you should use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_id]/oauth2` endpoint and use `resource` not `scope` when acquiring access token .

[Microsoft identity platform (v2.0) overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)

[Azure Active Directory for developers (v1.0) overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview)